# Why are some Facebook Graph API Event fields undefined?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working with Facebook Events via the Graph. The documentation is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

I can access some of the fields such as id, name, start_time, and location without any trouble at all. But some of the fields are always undefined. Specifically, description is always undefined. However, the fields aren't undefined when I look at them via the Graph API Explorer.

This isn't just an isolated instance; it's happening all over my application. So I'm fairly certain that the error isn't typographical. The fields that are defined and undefined are always the same. For example, something as simple as the following returns accurate information across multiple events for each of the fields except description.

```
alert(facebookEventsArray[i].id);
alert(facebookEventsArray[i].name);
alert(facebookEventsArray[i].description);
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you wont get the `description` of an event. You can explicitly mention the `fields` you require in your call. For eg:

```
EVENT_ID/events?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,description
```